# Apache Name Virtual Hosts Not Working

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, namevirtualhost

I've looked at several answers here, but none of the solutions worked.  Here's what I have so far in my `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default` site (and it is enabled).  (No modifications to other files from the apt-get install of Apache on Ubuntu 12.10.)

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName site.com
    ServerAlias www.site.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/main/
        # Directory settings, etc., removed for conciseness 
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName s1.site.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/subdomains/s1
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName s2.site.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/subdomains/s2
</VirtualHost>
```

When I try to reload the server...

```
# apachectl -k graceful
apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1 for ServerName
[Mon Mar 18 19:37:00 2013] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts
```

Why are there no virtual hosts?

Comment: I spun up an Ubuntu system.  If I comment out the `NameVirtualHost` line from your config file, it works just fine (this setting is already enabled in `ports.conf`).

Comment: I wasn't sure it was worth that, but sure :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I spun up an Ubuntu system. If I comment out the `NameVirtualHost` line from your config file, it works just fine (this setting is already enabled in `ports.conf`).  I've been searching unsuccessfully for information on exactly why we're seeing this behavior.